# Applying jQuery event handlers to AJAX content

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, handler

I'm sure this is something that AJAX gurus learn very early on, but this is the first time I've run into it.  Using jQuery, I have assigned .click() handlers to certain CSS classes.  However, if I reload some of the content via AJAX, the .click() handlers are not firing for that content.

It seems I have two choices:

1. put my .click() handler assignments within a JScript function, and call it every time content is refreshed via AJAX.
2. use onclick="" rather than jQuery within my AJAX content.

So far, it seems #1 would be the best; it's more consistent and yields smaller HTML for AJAX.

Is there another way to do it?  Perhaps a different way of assigning the .click() handlers from the outset?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for the [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method instead.

```
$('selector').live('click', function(){
  // your code.......
});
```

The `live` works for elements present now or in the future.

Comment: Wow, I'm glad I asked.  I had no idea that existed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you are using jQuery 1.4+, .live() is part of the core.  If not then there is a plugin called livequery that provides the functionality you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the bind or live methods, check this out: http://api.jquery.com/live/